# Website deployed on IIS not getting the domain NT login

Tags: asp.net, iis

I deployed my ASP.net Website on a server using IIS. The problem is that it denies Access to anyone accessing the website on the same domain. What i do is once a user tries to Access the website on the server i read the NT login for the user and match it to NT logins present in my Db and give the person Access if he his/her NT login is present in the DB. Now After Debugging i checked the variable used which stores the User NT login before checking it with the DB, and no matter who access the website the Login passed is the one for the server on which the website is deployed.

Webcofig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
       <identity impersonate="true" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
          <files>
              <add value="User_login_Portal.aspx" />
          </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="myConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Server=Server;Database=Backend_UM;User 
   ID=sa;Password=Password;Trusted_Connection=False;" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

ASPCode:

```
     string x = Environment.UserName;
        string y = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string NTlogin = currentIdentity.Name.ToString();



        string[] login_name = NTlogin.Split('\\');
        login = loginid.Text = login_name[1];
```

Authentications:

Windows Authentication: Enabled

ASP.net impersonation : Enabled

Forum Authentication: Disabled

Anonymous Authentication : Disabled

Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

The Login Variable in the Asp code is suppose to be the NT login Username of the Person trying to Access it, but whoever tries to Access the Website the Login Variable is the Username of the Server On which the portal is deployed.

Comment: Please show the actual error page which contains all necessary information on the error itself. Without that, there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: There is no error. Read the last 3 lines again.

Comment: I have resolved this. There was a problem in the setting while deploying the website. I re deployed the website and checked the windows authentication check box and it works fine now.

Comment: If you find the answer, post it below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was resolved. While deploying the website i needed to check the windows authentication check box. Since i was not doing that before the website would only take the user name of the server on which it was deployed.